# Return the time properly formatted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this code that when the button is clicked it returns the current time. However it returns the time in a format that's pretty unreadable. How do I format this to look better?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Clockwork.API.Models;

namespace Clockwork.API.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CurrentTimeController : Controller
{
    // GET api/currenttime
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var serverTime = DateTime.Now;
        var ip = this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

        var returnVal = new CurrentTimeQuery
        {
            UTCTime = utcTime,
            ClientIp = ip,
            Time = serverTime
        };

        using (var db = new ClockworkContext())
        {
            db.CurrentTimeQueries.Add(returnVal);
            var count = db.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} records saved to database", count);

            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (var CurrentTimeQuery in db.CurrentTimeQueries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - {0}", CurrentTimeQuery.UTCTime);
            }
        }

        return Ok(returnVal);
    }
}
}
```

It returns like this :

```
 {"currentTimeQueryId":15,"time":"2018-08-19T11:44:54.3348267-04:00","clientIp":"127.0.0.1","utcTime":"2018-08-19T15:44:54.3348267Z"}
```

Comment: `{0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}` is one of many formatting options...

Comment: In what specific format do you want it to be? You normally use `DateTime.ToString` with some format

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: If you're presenting it to a user, sure. If you're trying to create a machine-readable format like JSON, ISO-8601 is almost always the most appropriate format already.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Well, "looks better" doesn't sound like a machine-readable format to me :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: But the output is JSON. That's not *designed* to be human-readable. If the aim is to display the data to humans, JSON's not the best format for that purpose. Basically the OP needs to decide one way or the other: human consumption (not JSON, probably culture-sensitive) or machine consumption (JSON, culture-insensitive).

Comment: Is there a way to make this just display better?

Comment: @DaisyShipton So...? Sorry, but that's your opinion. If I have a single JavaScript client and it's for an internal application, I'll return the JSON with the format that's the easiest to work with in JavaScript. I certainly wouldn't return myself JSON like that to use a third-party library to format the date to a human-readable format

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that's exactly what I'm looking for, to be able to format it to make it readable for humans

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: But this *is* a format that's easy to work with in Javascript - you can then format it into a human readable format there (again, easily). In particular, at the Javascript layer you're likely to know culture information that is appropriate for the user, which may well not be relevant to the service at all. This isn't just for dates - it's for numbers too. Would you format a number as a string before returning it in JSON too, so that you could represent 10.5 as "10,5" for a user in France, for example? I believe you should leave presentation logic to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to change it at all.

That's an ISO-8601-formatted date and time including a UTC offset. That's good - it's easy to parse for pretty much any system out there. It's unambiguous, and doesn't have any culture-specific details like day and month names. It's great - for machines to read.

You're producing JSON, which is intended to be *machine*-readable, not *human*-readable. Sure, as an interchange format it *is* pretty readable, but it's not intended to be displayed to an end user. Instead, whatever is presenting the data to the end user should perform whatever formatting is appropriate for the date/time value. It's really important *not* to try to do that in the data transport format intended for machines (JSON in this case) as it can often lead to ambiguity or pointless culture-sensitivity.

Note that this isn't just for dates and times. Take a numeric value, for example: while 10.5 may be "human-readable" to you, it's not how someone in France would want to see "10 and a half". They'd format that as "10,5". But I wouldn't recommend using that string in the JSON: I'd make it 10.5 (as a number, not a string<sup>1</sup>) and then perform the "number to human-readable-format" conversion in Javascript.

Basically, keep data as presentation-agnostic as possible all the way through your data pipeline until it reaches the presentation layer, which should have all the cultural information required to format it ideally for the actual user. Very often you *don't* have all that cultural information elsewhere in the pipeline.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless you're trying to account for JSON being binary floating point when you're trying to represent a strictly decimal number. It's unfortunate that there's no real decimal format in JSON.

Comment: Is there a way to show machine readable and human readable. It's supposed to be an app to display the time, not really meant for machine readable.

Comment: @BThomps: *What* is an app to display the time? What's consuming the JSON? If it's a web application, then format the date/time there. Bear in mind that different humans may well want to see the data in different ways. For example, in the UK today is 20/08/2018, whereas in the US someone write that as 08/20/2018. For dates like "August 7th" that becomes ambiguous. You can remove that ambiguity using month names - but which language do you use for those? These are all cultural concerns that should usually be handled by the presentation layer.

Comment: what is the syntax to format that is the question I'm asking.

Comment: @BThomps: The syntax to format what, where? It's unclear what your context is: what's consuming this JSON? *That's* what should be performing formatting, IMO. If that's Javascript, then you should do research into how to format date/time values within Javascript.

Comment: I just want the code below to display in a more human readable format.

     {"currentTimeQueryId":15,"time":"2018-08-19T11:44:54.3348267-04:00","clientIp":"127.0.0.1","utcTime":"2018-08-19T15:44:54.3348267Z"}

Comment: @asmart: But that still doesn't explain why you're showing a user JSON to start with. JSON isn't *designed* to be shown to users. Without any more context than what you've already stated, it's very hard to give concrete advice.

Comment: it's a project given this way that my task is to "beautify" I'm not sure why it's written this way unfortunately.

Comment: @asmart: The way to "beautify" it is not to present the JSON to the user directly. Unfortunately as we still don't know what's consuming the JSON or any other context, we still can't give you any more help on that. But the JSON itself is already in a highly appropriate format for a date/time value. Is there any reason you're reluctant to give us more context than "it's a project"?

Comment: I don't know how to look up what you're asking for. And I don't have the stack overflow "reputation" to move this to a chat.

Comment: @asmart: I'm not asking for anything you should need to look up - I'm asking for more information about the project. You're producing some JSON - what for? What uses the JSON? Is it a web service? A web page? Does it display the JSON directly, or does it parse it and then display the fields individually? Perhaps it's being consumed by a "thick client" like a Windows Forms application or WPF? Something else? This information is crucial to helping you find the best path.

Comment: the project is a web application using an API to call to a database. The webpage has a button you click which calls the API and displays the information that I'm trying to format.

Comment: @asmart: Right. So you need to change the Javascript that's calling the API so that it parses the date/time value, and *that* should format it. You might want to use Moment.js for that, for example. That doesn't involve changing the JSON format at all.

Comment: do you have a link of example?

Comment: @asmart: Well I'd start at https://momentjs.com/. I'm not a Javascript developer though. My point is that this *isn't* a problem with the JSON you're producing. That's already in a good, standardized format. You just need to separate the concerns of an API returning data from *presenting* the data. How exactly you do that is a separate matter - you can ask another question if you need to after doing appropriate research, but it wouldn't be a C# question.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: Except that as it's producing JSON, that's a bad idea - it would then be potentially ambiguous for anything trying to read the JSON afterwards. The idea is that JSON is *machine-readable*, which the OP's output already is.